# Doctrine2 annotation issue

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I have a project that uses Doctrine 2.0, works rather well.  I tried to upgrade to 2.2.2, however I have noticed several differences:

/**
 * Entities\Log
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="log")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\LogRepository")
 */

Is how it is shown in 2.2.2.

But this is how it is shown in 2.0.x:

/**
 * Entities\Log
 *
 * @Table(name="log")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\LogRepository")
 */

If I convert the 2.2.2, to look like 2.0, everything is fine, it loads up, and there is a copy of the object in cache.  However, when I leave it alone I get this error:

Application Path: /www/sites/diracianbilling-repository/trunk/application
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class Entities\Log is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:147
Stack trace:

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you generated your entities from the database.

Doctrine 2.2.2 for some reason generates these annotations that itself cannot parse. This is obviously a bug.

As a workaround you can configure the generator to provide 2.0-style annotations. Use the [solution from dminer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065606/generate-annotated-doctrine2-entites-from-db-schema) and add the following line just before generating:

```
$generator->setAnnotationPrefix("");
```